# Cannot Install Ubuntu 16.04.3 on VMWare, but can install 16.04.1

Tags: system-installation, vmware

I know there are several "cannot install Ubuntu" posts here, but I haven't found my answer yet, so I turn to you.

System:

- Intel Pentium G4600 Skylake CPU
- MSI B250M Pro-VDH LGA 1511 motherboard
- 8 GB DDR4 RAM
- 1 TB HDD
- Intel HD 630 graphics
- Windows 10 64-bit
- VMWare Pro Version 12.0

I can install Ubuntu version 16.04.1 with no problem, and even upgrade it to the newest version and it seems stable so far (after a few hours of playing around in it). The problem is when I attempt a typical install of Ubuntu version 16.04.2 or .3. I assign it 1 CPU core and 1 GB of RAM, and then I tell VMWare to install the OS on the VM. From there, any number of errors happen. I will give details of the problems I've had with installing Ubuntu 16.04.3 on VMWare in the hopes that the community can see something I've missed:

1. Once installation initializes, the VM shows a purple screen that says "Ubuntu" with a few loading dots under it. After a few seconds of that, it cuts to a console that describes how the installation process is going ("76%: Copying files" and the like). Sometimes, it will just hang while it copies files.
2. Occasionally, the console will say "Installation complete" and then just hang. If I reboot, then it gets stuck on a black screen.
3. Sometimes, it does install successfully and takes me to a login screen. However, it won't list the username I defined. If I try to put in my username and password, Ubuntu says "Invalid username or password", as if it didn't actually copy my credentials over from when I built the VM.
4. Sometimes, it finishes installing and I can actually log in. When this happens, it brings me to an empty desktop (no shortcuts or sidebar). Immediately after, a stream of error messages pop up. I try to click on the details, but more and more messages pop up and the desktop hangs or gets slow.

One other error I've gotten:[Dependency failed for Swap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re8IP.jpg)

I've seen one or two other Swap errors during installation, but I'm not sure that's the main problem.

So. Does anyone have any ideas, or have you seen anything like this? Again, I can reliably install Ubuntu 16.04.1 on VMWare. It's just the newer versions that struggle. What can I do to be able to install the newest version of Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.3 can be reliably installed on a VMware virtual machine. What you are trying to do is an "express installation" performed by VMware Workstation or Player. I don't know about this kind of installation because I don't use it. But you will find that booting your VM from the installation ISO image and performing a regular install works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this was an easy one. I was running VMWare Workstation Pro version 12.0.0, provided by my school. After I installed the latest update (version 12.5.8), things seem to be working just fine.

Because I built this PC myself, I was assuming that something must have been wrong with the hardware.